# get content of local html file with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, file, local

what i need is passing local html file to my form, get content of this file and later parse it.
I have this in view

```
  = form_tag :parser, :html => {:multipart => true} do
    = file_field_tag :html_file
    = submit_tag
```

And this in controller

```
  def parser
    @file = params[:html_file]
  end
```

It seems like form dont get file, just get the string with name of file. How to fix it?

Comment: ahhh, get it, it's haml. need just :multipart => true instead of html => {:multipart => true}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this to handle uploads in a Rails 2.3.x app.  I cannot remember why I had to split this into an if/elsif/else/end statement, but I must have had an error consolidating it to one if statement.

```
    if %w(File Tempfile ActionController::UploadedTempfile ).include?(params[:html_file].class.to_s)          
      data = params[:html_file].read
    elsif %w(StringIO ActionController::UploadedStringIO).include?(params[:html_file].class.to_s)
      data = params[:html_file].read
    else
      logger.error("File does not appear to be a valid class.")
    end
```